# Calling a function when an object is created

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a function when I create a new object with my constructor?

```
let people = [];

function person(first, last){
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
}

let john = new person(john, doe);
```

Now I want every person that is made to be pushed into an array. Do I have to write array.push out after each creation?

Comment: Well from a pure OOP point of view constructor should only create a new instance and not interact outside of its scope, but it's javascript....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use for `People` another instance and add `Person` to the array.

This approach does not includes side effects of `Person`, because pushing to `people` is covered by `People` class.

```js
function People() {
    this.people = [];
    this.createPerson = function (first, last) {
        this.people.push(new Person(first, last));
    };
    this.getPeople = function () {
        return this.people;
    };
}

function Person(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
}

var people = new People;

people.createPerson('john', 'doe');

console.log(people);
console.log(people.getPeople());
console.log(people.getPeople()[0] instanceof Person);
```

Comment: This seems strange to me. It has most upvotes so I am sure it is right but is it not a problem to use People and people? Also why is people an array in the constructor and then a new People below?

Comment: `people` is an instance of `People`. you could add another method, like `getPeople` and you get the wanted array with all instances of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let people = [];

function person(first, last){
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
   people.push(this);
}

let john = new person(john, doe);
```

Comment: That creates a very direct relationship between the array, and the object/class itself. What if there was no such array, or that name was already used by a variable of a different type for example? I’d rather use a function that creates a new person, and then adds that new person to an array, so that those two different functionalities don’t get tangled this much.

Comment: Well I think the op wasn't asking how to do (quite trivial) but if it's a good practice or not

Comment: @CBroe well if that were the case, it should be included in the question.

Comment: @Gab yup I guess its quite trivial, but the question was if it was necessary to call a function after each object creation, to which the answer is no.

Comment: This is your point of view, and from mine, this is a very poor design, as stated by CBroe :)

Comment: @Gab the question wasn't really about point of views or software design. If it were, I would suggest creating a Proxy around Person to decrease coupling between the class and the array. That way you wouldn't even need to introduce a new class like Nina Scholz suggested. However, I had people tutored who didn't think about the possibility to use the 'this' reference inside a constructor for anything other than assigning attribute values. And judging from OP's question, he/she didn't think about this option either.

Answer (score 0):

Your `person` constructor is being called before you create your `people` array.

```js
let people = [];

function person(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.pushToPerson = function() {
    people.push(this);
  }
  this.pushToPerson();
}

let john = new person("john", "doe");
console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let people = [];

    function add (firstName, lastName) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.firstName = firstName;
    obj.lastName = lastName;
    people.push(obj);
    }

    add('John', 'Doe');
    add('Sarah', 'Smith');
    
    console.log(people);
```